# How get path between two point on map?

Tags: 7

I want to use an API that gives me the path between two points. I know the value of latitude and longitude.

How do I get path, latitude and longitude of points of in between path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the [Google Maps Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters), although I don't know any Drupal module that handles this API out of the box.